# How to update Vim to color-code new html elements

Tags: vim, html

I am wondering how I might set vim to color the new html5 elements (ie "canvas" and "video") as it does with the existing "script", "body" elements (or reserved words in other languages like python's "def") etc.  Current version is from MacPorts typically used in a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`html.vim` is the syntax file Vim consults to determine which tags will be colored. The location of this will depend on your installation of Vim. Within this syntax file you'll see many lines that look like the following:

```
" new html 4.0 tags
syn keyword htmlTagName contained abbr acronym bdo button col label
syn keyword htmlTagName contained colgroup del fieldset iframe ins legend
syn keyword htmlTagName contained object optgroup q s tbody tfoot thead
```

These lines define syntax keywords. In this case they specifically define HTML tag names. The first line tells Vim to color `abbr`, `acronym`, `bdo`, `button`, `col`, and `label` tags. You can tell Vim to color additional tags with the following syntax:

```
" new html 5 tags
syn keyword htmlTagName contained video canvas
```

Vim will now color `video` and `canvas` tags and any additional keywords you add.

However if you update the built-in `html.vim` it will get overwritten the next time you update Vim, so the best practice is to append your rules to these built-in ones. To do so create the folder path `after/syntax` in your `.vim` folder and place a `html.vim` in it.

There are a large number of the HTML 5 elements and arguments in this [gist](http://gist.github.com/390929) mentioned by @user240515 below. Paste the contents of this into your newly create `html.vim`.

Consult `:help html.vim` for some more info.

Comment: @michaelmichael thanks, but for me is not working, I added the lines that @johan said in his answer but I'm not getting highlighting in `<footer>` tag for example... The permissions of the folders/file are the same as in the regular syntax files. Here you have the content of the file: http://pastebin.com/cp8qYDze

Comment: I  downloaded the complete syntax file for HTML5 from [othree project](https://github.com/othree/html5.vim/blob/master/syntax/html.vim) and saved it to the recommended path `vimfiles/after/syntax` (I'm on windows), but that didn't work for me either.

But once I moved it to `vimfiles/syntax` (as intended), it started working! `<main>`, `<footer>` etc., everything is nicely colored. But I had to keep the original name `html.vim`. First I saved it as `html5.vim` and for whatever reason it didn't work.

I don't understand why the accepted answer recommends `after/syntax` path...

Answer (score 22):

Thanks for this question, and thanks for the accepted answer! This is a complete list of the new tags to add for html 5, as they are defined at the time of writing:

```
" new html 5 tags
syn keyword htmlTagName contained article aside audio canvas command datalist
syn keyword htmlTagName contained details embed figcaption figure footer header
syn keyword htmlTagName contained hgroup keygen mark meter nav output progress
syn keyword htmlTagName contained rp rt ruby section source summary time video
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm just about to try this one:

http://github.com/othree/html5.vim

Seems pretty complete.

EDIT:  I don't see anything about indentation.  :(

EDIT [12/23/2012]: I do :) But maybe is was added later: https://github.com/othree/html5.vim/tree/master/indent

Comment: nice, omnicomplete for huge amounts of html5 javascript api's  ("onmousewheel", "ondragstart")

Comment: One way to install it is: `git clone https://github.com/othree/html5.vim` then go to that directory and execute: `make install`. It will install all required files into your ~/.vim directory. It takes about 1 second.

Answer (score 7):

Just put the following file in ~/.vim/syntax:

http://gist.github.com/390929

Comment: I had trouble doing this; instead renamed it to "html.vim" and put it in .vim/after/syntax

Answer (score 4):

Indentation can be supported using an approach similar to that described by michaelmichael for extending the `html.vim` syntax file.  If you don't already have `html.vim` in `~/.vim/indent` you can create it with the content found [here](http://web-indent.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9/trunk/indent/html.vim).  Within the `~/.vim/indent/html.vim` you'll see a set of function calls assembling a list of HTML element names that looks like the following:

```
" [-- <ELEMENT ? - - ...> --]
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('a')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('abbr')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('acronym')
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('address')
" ...and many more...
```

These lines are defining the tags that will trigger basic tag indenting.  Extend this list with any HTML5 tags that you want to have trigger indenting.  I added the following to the end of this list:

```
" New HTML 5 elements
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('table')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('article')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('aside')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('audio')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('canvas')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('command')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('datalist')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('details')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('embed')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('figcaption')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('figure')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('footer')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('header')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('hgroup')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('keygen')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('mark')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('meter')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('nav')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('output')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('progress')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('rp')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('rt')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('ruby')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('section')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('source')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('summary')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('time')
call<SID>HtmlIndentPush('video')
```

Indenting will now be triggered on the HTML5 tags listed above.

Answer (score 4):

I added an html5 indent file to a fork of othree/html5.vim based on the suggestions above.

See http://github.com/briangershon/html5.vim

Answer (score 0):

The `syntax/html.vim` file that comes with vim (8.0) is *very* outdated.  A good way to keep your syntax highlighting updated is to use a well maintained plugin such as [vim-polygot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot) which is kept much more up-to-date.  It's [html.vim syntax](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/blob/master/syntax/html.vim) supports, `canvas`, `video`, `section` and `main` (which other answers do not support), to name a few.