# Editing HTML5 with Vim

Tags: vim, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update Vim to color-code new html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232518/how-to-update-vim-to-color-code-new-html-elements)

Default Vim HTML syntax/indent files do not know anything about new HTML5 tags. What is the best way to add support for HTML5 to Vim?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232518/how-to-update-vim-to-color-code-new-html-elements

Comment: That's a good question, I'm interested in hearing the response for this. I've just been waiting for a VIM update with updated syntax/indent files because I tried looking at the code for syntax highlighting and indenting and it makes my head hurt. Seriously. -EDIT: thanks for the duplicate reference... looks like everything's all been sorted out.

Comment: @akira, thanks for duplicate reference. Unfortunately, Vim it seems like vim indent file (indent/html.vim) needs similar changes to correctly work with new tags.