# Dynamically Detect HTML5 in vim

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, vim

This is related to [How to update Vim to color-code new html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232518/how-to-update-vim-to-color-code-new-html-elements), but I want the syntax highlighter to only highlight the elements if it detects the html5 doctype at the first line of the file. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would add something like this to the top of the `html.vim` syntax file:

```
if getline(1) =~? '<!DOCTYPE html>'
  let b:html5 = 1
else
  let b:html5 = 0
endif
```

And then throughout the syntax file you can use `if b:html5` to check if html5 is being used for the current buffer.

```
if b:html5
  " new html 5 tags
  syn keyword htmlTagName contained video canvas
endif
```

Comment: This is pretty great. I assume the =~? '' bit would be replaced with either a regex or a string, i.e., =~? '<!doctype html>'?

Comment: Yes, sorry the angle brackets made everything disappear.