# How to make Vim support new Html5 tags?

Tags: html, vim

Everything is in the question. When I use new Html5 tags in Vim, they don't get colored and they don't indent. So I have to indent them myself. Is there a technique for Vim to support Html5 tags?
Thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update Vim to color-code new html elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232518/how-to-update-vim-to-color-code-new-html-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this patch in the base directory of your vim installation:

https://gist.github.com/1254928